# Very fast serialization. Random access C++

Tags: c++, serialization, c++11

What can I use to perform fast serialization of data into several files in C++11 (to avoid data redundancy I assume that I will split data into several tables and join them on its id numbers)?

I think about using:

1. simple binary files accessed with `fstream.read()`, `fstream.write()`.
2. using `mmap`.
3. function google `protobuf` (if I can access random element instead of iterating on all of them).

All tables will consist of columns with following datatypes: 
`uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `string`.

Comment: Serialization and I/O are different things. I would not worry too much about serialization speed itself when you have to deal with files..

Comment: My first inclination would be to consider [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: SQLite is not an option, when I have to handle a lot of data(sqlite file has about 8GB).

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB

Comment: @MiniKarol: I wasn't aware that SQLite had a file size limit that small. Indeed, I'm pretty sure [this is not true.](http://sqlite.org/limits.html) It says 1 Tera-pages is the default maximum size. And a page is several bytes; I don't know how many, but if it's 1KB, then that's 1024 Tera-bytes for the maximum file size.

Comment: Have you made more progress on your project? I'm interested in the tradeoffs you've made or discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast random access will be the challenge here.  The easiest way to achieve that is to keep each row constant size.  There's no easy way to do that using `protobuf`s, unless you assume a conservative maximum size.  It should be relatively easy to do this with either of your first two options (assuming you have a reasonable limit on the size of the string).

You can get arbitrarily more complicated, however.  Using `protobuf`s will likely use less space than a naive serialization, so you'll have memory left over to build an index.  Even a relatively small index (say, mapping from a table row number to a file offset for every 100th row) will give you fast random access and use a lot less space.  Of course, this is quite a bit more complicated than the simple every-row-is-the-same-size approach.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your numeric and string storage.

**Sparse Tables, Numeric Data**

Use a column store for numeric typed columns. Column stores do not store NULL values, and provide join logic allowing you to reproduce table rows.

Not single-lookup random access, but the space tradeoff may win, especially if the column store's indexes stay in memory.

**Dense Tables, Numeric Data**

MMAP a file for reading. Store your data row-wise, with constant width. You may have to tweak file open parameters to get desired cache and readahead benefits.

It's probably faster to do your writing using fstream.write().

**String Data**

Based on your suggestions, it sounds like your design allows writing the table all at once, and then performing read-only random access from that point forward. If so, look at [Google's SSTable](http://www.igvita.com/2012/02/06/sstable-and-log-structured-storage-leveldb/). It's a storage layer that provides efficient random access for variable length data.

Answer (score 1):

The MIT-licensed serialization library **[Cap’n Proto](https://capnproto.org)** might provide the functionality you need. It was written by the main author of Google Protobuf **Kenton Varda**.

A [quote](https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/issues/131) from him:
*Cap'n Proto uses pointers to support fully random access. This means you can do things like mmap() a giant file and pull out one inner object without actually processing the whole thing, or access sub-objects in a different order than they were written*

The data types you are mentioning (uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, string) are all supported by the [Cap'n Proto Schema Language](https://capnproto.org/language.html)